# In Rcpp, why can't I assign a subsetted vector to another subsetted vector

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I'm currently porting some R code into Rcpp for a speed improvement (which has been successful so far), but I'm trying to understand why Rcpp doesn't allow certain types of assignment when it comes to subsetting.

For example, in R if I have three vectors A, B, C, and if for some condition of C i want to fill A with the values of B, then i can write:

```
A[C < 3] = B[C< 3]
```

However I get an error when i try something similar in Rcpp.

Rccp seems to be happy to assign things like:

```
A[C < 3] = X
```

...and...

```
Y = B[C< 3]
```

...but not...

```
A[C < 3] = B[C< 3]
```

Therefore I first assign the RHS to another vector first, and then assign that vector to the LHS, it works fine!?

Here is some example code that works:

```
cppFunction("
    NumericVector valuesOverThree(NumericVector b){

        NumericVector a(b.size());

        NumericVector temp = b[b > 3];
        a[b > 3] = temp;
        return a;
    }
")
valuesOverThree(1:6)
# returns: [0, 0, 0, 4, 5, 6]
```

And here is some that gives an error:

```
cppFunction("
    NumericVector valuesOverThree(NumericVector b){
        NumericVector a(b.size());

        a[b > 3] = b[b > 3];
        return a;
    }
")
valuesOverThree(1:6)
# returns: error message
```

Is there any reason for this, or anyway I can make this work on one line?

As shown, there is a workaround, but it would be nicer if i could write everything on one line.

Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

We have a [Rcpp Gallery article](http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/subsetting/) on indexing / subsetting.

I have in the past used RcppArmadillo, there is [also an Rcpp Gallery post](http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/armadillo-subsetting/) besides the [normal (and excellent) Armadillo documentation](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html).

I also would not worry too much about getting everything onto one line.  The compiler is pretty good at removing temporaries.  Rather, I try to write code I can still read in a week.

Comment: Thanks @dirk-eddelbuettel ...yes I had come across that gallery article and it was very useful, although doesn't address the example I've described. I was just curious if their was a bit of syntax i was missing. But as you say its probably not worth stressing over, and may even be clearer to use multiple lines. Thanks!

Comment: It's possible that we could make this happen -- I'll file an Rcpp issue.

Answer (score 1):

Just a simple remainder.

You can do exactly what you want with latest Rcpp.

```
> cppFunction("
+     NumericVector valuesOverThree(NumericVector b){
+         NumericVector a(b.size());
+ 
+         a[b > 3] = b[b > 3];
+         return a;
+     }
+ ")
> valuesOverThree(1:6)
[1] 0 0 0 4 5 6
>
```